# Skype video chat : how to enlarge one participant's video?

Tags: skype, conferencing

I am taking online dance lessons with Skype.
There are usually 5 participants plus the teacher, so each video is fairly small (I am using a laptop with a 14" screen, I don't have anything else).

How can I enlarge the teacher's video ?